# Export Products Error - Entity is unknown

Tags: product, error, importexport, export, entities

I tried to export my products with images but i am getting the error "`Entity is unknown`" occurs. Someone knows how to export manually or how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: are you using magento default import export functionality. if so go for System> import/export > Export all products & Run profile.

Comment: @Baby-in-Magento I have done that already, but it deleted all existing products....

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefront and set its value to No.

I hope it will fix this issue. I has tested this solutions on Magento 1.9.3.